# In case that I cannot know whether datetime is offset-aware or not, how to subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetime?

Tags: python, timezone

I am having a hard time dealing with timezone. Can somebody give me some advice?

It is not known whether the time 'lastday' is offset-aware or not. In this case, how can I subtract two time 'lastday' and 'today'?

Assuming that 'lastday' is offset-aware, 
by executing the following code:

```
lastday = snapshotinfo.dateCreated
print 'lastday:',lastday
today = datetime.datetime.today()
print 'today:',today
today = pytz.utc.localize(today)
print 'today after localize:',today
diff = abs(today - lastday).days
print 'diff:', diff
```

I can get the following result

```
lastday: 2017-03-27 00:24:16.295000+09:00
today: 2017-03-27 18:23:41.284000
today after localize: 2017-03-27 18:23:41.284000+00:00
diff: 1
```

But on another server,'lastday' is offset-naive. In this case, I get the following error:

```
lastday: 2017-03-27 00:23:21.000215
today: 2017-03-27 18:33:34.883176
today after localize: 2017-03-27 18:33:34.883176+00:00
diff = abs(today - lastday).days
TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

How do I know whether 'lastday' is offset-naive or not? If I can know it, I think I can decide whether or not to convert 'today'.

Comment: I've used `thing.tzname() is None` as a check for naive datetimes.

Comment: Subtracting TZ-aware and TZ-naive datetimes in a mixed fashion does not make sense.   At least the hours of the results are meaningless (and I wouldn't count on the days as well).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I modified my script with your advice. Can you tell me what the difference is between 09:00 and 00:00? Should I match 00:00 with 09:00?

Comment: What are you actually wanting to know?  If you are interested in only the day difference between one value's year-month-day bits and another value's year-month-day bits, you certainly can do that even when one is naive and one is aware.  You just can't interpret the results as being in terms of 24-hour whole days.  All you will learn is how many boxes on a calendar have been traversed.